# (Bulk) email not arriving. Unclear why

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server

Please bear with me while I try to explain the problem the best I can (English is not my native language).

One of my clients offers an online entertainment show aimed at companies whose employees need to work from home now due to the Corona pandemic. This is streamed live through YouTube. Each show is tailored for the company requesting the show.

When a company signs up for a show, they need to submit a list with email addresses of the employees wanting to attend the online show. *My* mail server then sends out a standard email (on behalf of my client) to each employee with a small text introducing the show and a link to a YouTube stream.

I've done everything I can think of to make sure the mail arrives:

I've added a SPF record to my client's DNS to inform a receiving mail server my domain is authorized to send email on behalf of my client.
I've added a DKIM record
I've added a DMARC record

Before I send out the email campaign, I always have my server send a sample to mail-tester.com. I always get a perfect 10 out of 10 score:

[image]

Even so, most of the time a small percentage of the sent email, doesn't arrive. Even though all mail was sent to email addresses on the same domain (from the client). I chalk this up to people accidentally deleting the mail, or perhaps they have an overactive virus scanner on their system.

Anyway, yesterday I needed to send out an email campaign to my client's customer's employees. None arrived. I tried again and again none arrived. I have no clue as to why. I've copied a part of the relevant lines of my mail.info log file. I don't exactly know how to read the log file, but I don't see any apparent errors.

I've changed the domain names as follows:

- onlineentertainment.com is my client's company
- mymailserver.com is my mail server
- recipientdomain.com is the domain name of the company of which employees I'm trying to send emails to.

Can anyone see what might be going on here?

```
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/pickup[39522]: 7B6595F979: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 7B6595F979: message-id=<20201216225437.7B6595F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 7B6595F979: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4113, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/pickup[39522]: D03835F97D: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: D03835F97D: message-id=<20201216225437.D03835F97D@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:37 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: D03835F97D: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4133, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/pickup[39522]: 313375F97E: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 313375F97E: message-id=<20201216225438.313375F97E@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 313375F97E: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4141, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: 4B5CC5F977: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 4B5CC5F977: message-id=<20201216225437.7B6595F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 4B5CC5F977: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5132, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise amavis[34564]: (34564-15) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <anke@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225437.7B6595F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: 92QAoDnqQmRn, Hits: -2.099, size: 4622, queued_as: 4B5CC5F977, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 808 ms
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtp[2762]: 7B6595F979: to=<anke@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.82, delays=0.01/0/0/0.81, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4B5CC5F977)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 7B6595F979: removed
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/pickup[39522]: 877355F97F: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 877355F97F: message-id=<20201216225438.877355F97F@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 877355F97F: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4112, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: 9D4475F979: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 9D4475F979: message-id=<20201216225437.D03835F97D@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=3 rcpt=3 data=3 noop=1 quit=1 commands=12
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 9D4475F979: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5162, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise amavis[58567]: (58567-03) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <anne-lies@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225437.D03835F97D@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: MIeaBhcawP2y, Hits: -2.099, size: 4642, queued_as: 9D4475F979, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 779 ms
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/smtp[3129]: D03835F97D: to=<anne-lies@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.81, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.78, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9D4475F979)
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: D03835F97D: removed
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/pickup[39522]: DE1525F980: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: DE1525F980: message-id=<20201216225438.DE1525F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:38 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: DE1525F980: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4109, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: 2A03F5F97D: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 2A03F5F97D: message-id=<20201216225438.313375F97E@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 2A03F5F97D: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5174, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise amavis[34564]: (34564-16) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <anne-marie@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225438.313375F97E@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: QfInV79FpesV, Hits: -2.099, size: 4650, queued_as: 2A03F5F97D, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 856 ms
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtp[2762]: 313375F97E: to=<anne-marie@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.99, delays=0.01/0.11/0.01/0.86, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2A03F5F97D)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 313375F97E: removed
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: 5BE7C5F981: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 5BE7C5F981: message-id=<20201216225439.5BE7C5F981@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 5BE7C5F981: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4108, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: 8047B5F97E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 8047B5F97E: message-id=<20201216225438.877355F97F@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 8047B5F97E: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5129, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise amavis[58567]: (58567-04) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <anouk@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225438.877355F97F@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: abrUz0K5KSll, Hits: -2.099, size: 4621, queued_as: 8047B5F97E, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 882 ms
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtp[3129]: 877355F97F: to=<anouk@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.99, delays=0.01/0.1/0/0.88, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8047B5F97E)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 877355F97F: removed
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: CB0395F982: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: CB0395F982: message-id=<20201216225439.CB0395F982@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: CB0395F982: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4124, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/smtp[3134]: 4B5CC5F977: to=<anke@recipientdomain.com>, relay=recipientdomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[123.12.9.36]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.01/0.01/0.27/1.3, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20201216225437.7B6595F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com> [InternalId=29476360558290, Hostname=AM6PR08MB4674.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com] 15208 bytes in 0.138, 107.008 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Dec 16 23:54:39 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 4B5CC5F977: removed
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: 090B75F977: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 090B75F977: message-id=<20201216225438.DE1525F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 090B75F977: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5126, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise amavis[34564]: (34564-16-2) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <anouk@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225438.DE1525F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: 9OD8VAmXIwx9, Hits: -2.099, size: 4618, queued_as: 090B75F977, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 859 ms
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtp[2762]: DE1525F980: to=<anouk@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=2, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/0.28/0/0.86, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 090B75F977)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: DE1525F980: removed
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: 46D3D5F980: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 46D3D5F980: message-id=<20201216225440.46D3D5F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 46D3D5F980: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4104, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: 6D3E55F97F: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 6D3E55F97F: message-id=<20201216225439.5BE7C5F981@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 6D3E55F97F: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5121, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise amavis[58567]: (58567-04-2) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <arne@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225439.5BE7C5F981@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: HWq-d2xorNb9, Hits: -2.099, size: 4617, queued_as: 6D3E55F97F, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 917 ms
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtp[3129]: 5BE7C5F981: to=<arne@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=2, delay=1.1, delays=0.02/0.16/0/0.92, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6D3E55F97F)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 5BE7C5F981: removed
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtp[3139]: 9D4475F979: to=<anne-lies@recipientdomain.com>, relay=recipientdomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[123.12.10.36]:25, delay=2, delays=0.01/0.02/0.21/1.8, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20201216225437.D03835F97D@enterprise.mymailserver.com> [InternalId=53919019439079, Hostname=DB6PR0801MB2088.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com] 14660 bytes in 0.243, 58.906 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 9D4475F979: removed
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtp[3134]: 090B75F977: to=<anouk@recipientdomain.com>, relay=recipientdomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[123.12.8.36]:25, delay=0.65, delays=0.01/0/0.07/0.57, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20201216225438.DE1525F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com> [InternalId=7189775259089, Hostname=VI1PR08MB3775.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com] 14799 bytes in 0.136, 105.753 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 090B75F977: removed
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: B76765F979: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: B76765F979: message-id=<20201216225440.B76765F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: B76765F979: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4148, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: EE50E5F977: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: EE50E5F977: message-id=<20201216225439.CB0395F982@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: EE50E5F977: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5145, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise amavis[34564]: (34564-16-3) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <arthur@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225439.CB0395F982@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: 2t01vbNEsLgw, Hits: -2.099, size: 4633, queued_as: EE50E5F977, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 937 ms
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/smtp[2762]: CB0395F982: to=<arthur@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=3, delay=1.2, delays=0.01/0.22/0/0.94, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as EE50E5F977)
Dec 16 23:54:40 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: CB0395F982: removed
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/smtp[3153]: 8047B5F97E: to=<anouk@recipientdomain.com>, relay=recipientdomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[123.12.10.36]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.01/0.02/0.17/1.3, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20201216225438.877355F97F@enterprise.mymailserver.com> [InternalId=39006892988455, Hostname=AM7PR08MB5334.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com] 14696 bytes in 0.072, 197.088 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 8047B5F97E: removed
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: 3E6035F981: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 3E6035F981: message-id=<20201216225441.3E6035F981@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 3E6035F981: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4116, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/smtpd[2771]: 4EAFD5F97E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: 4EAFD5F97E: message-id=<20201216225440.46D3D5F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 4EAFD5F97E: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5115, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise amavis[58567]: (58567-04-3) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [127.0.0.1] <info@onlineentertainment.com> -> <bo@recipientdomain.com>, Message-ID: <20201216225440.46D3D5F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>, mail_id: 18YuKNQ-nYvh, Hits: -2.099, size: 4613, queued_as: 4EAFD5F97E, dkim_sd=202011:onlineentertainment.com, 868 ms
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/smtp[3129]: 46D3D5F980: to=<bo@recipientdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=3, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/0.17/0/0.87, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4EAFD5F97E)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 46D3D5F980: removed
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/smtp[3145]: 2A03F5F97D: to=<anne-marie@recipientdomain.com>, relay=recipientdomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com[123.12.8.36]:25, delay=2.4, delays=0.01/0.02/0.1/2.3, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20201216225438.313375F97E@enterprise.mymailserver.com> [InternalId=28737626183423, Hostname=AM0PR08MB5073.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com] 14768 bytes in 0.153, 94.061 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: 2A03F5F97D: removed
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/pickup[3151]: B708C5F980: uid=33 from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: B708C5F980: message-id=<20201216225441.B708C5F980@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: B708C5F980: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=4131, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/smtpd[3133]: D806A5F97D: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/cleanup[2761]: D806A5F97D: message-id=<20201216225440.B76765F979@enterprise.mymailserver.com>
Dec 16 23:54:41 enterprise postfix/qmgr[41828]: D806A5F97D: from=<info@onlineentertainment.com>, size=5181, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Comment: Seems likely that Microsoft/Office 365 is classifying your messages as spam.

Comment: Perhaps, but based on what? mail-tester.com doesn't classify the email as spam and it uses (besides SPF, DKIM and DMARC authentication) spamassasin.

Comment: Microsoft do not disclose their algorithm.  Can be because of your sending rate (email per minute), because too many end users click the "junk" button (which gets recorded), or any combination of factors.

Comment: Your sender IP is listed in RATS https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3aonlineentertainment.com&run=toolpage Not sure if MS is checking this DB. Make sure you use SPF/DKIM/DMARC and they pass checks.
Normally when you don't get email to specific MBX you need to send to another mail server and to check headers upon arrival. If all checks passed.

Comment: I replaced the real domain name for "onlineentertainment.com" in the above log. The real domain name isn't listed in any blacklist. The email passes all SPF/DKIM/DMARC checks. I suspect it has something to do with the fact I'm sending a lot of email to the same mail server as fast as I can. Maybe I should build in a pause of a few seconds before sending the next email, so I don't exceed some kind of limit. But then if I need to send an email to a few hundred employees, that could take for ever...

Comment: Your recipients need to find the message in the Junk folder and click Not Junk. You should also be aware that I have seen Microsoft accept mail for delivery and then drop it on the floor, enough so that I steer people away from their email products.

Comment: They said the mail wasn't in their Junk folder either. I think what you said is exactly what happened. Their Outlook server accepted all mail, but did not deliver it to the recipients and simply dropped it. I guess only two solutions remain (but I'm not sure): Throttle my outgoing email, or have the client whitelist my mail server's IP.